# Does anyone know how to use letsum?

Tags: python, github, nlp, summarization

I am trying to do legal text summarization and found this open source package, but I don't know how to install and use it. I tried using `pip install letsum` but it's giving me an error.

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement letsum (from versions: none)`

`ERROR: No matching distribution found for letsum`

Below is the github documentation, any ideas how to use it?

https://github.com/Law-AI/summarization

Thank you in advance

Comment: I just edited the question, it says that they couldn't find letsum

Comment: It's not packaged for PyPI then. You should download or clone the repository and run it like any normal Python software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow these steps:

1. Clone the repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/Law-AI/summarization.git
```

2. Install dependencies

```
pip install -r summarization/supervised/requirements.txt
```

3. Get to `summarization/supervised/legal-specific/LetSum`:

```
cd summarization/supervised/legal-specific/LetSum
```

4. Open your IDE in the current directory and you should be able to `import letsum` without any problem!

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering my question, but I'm using google colab and when I tried to `import letsum`, it still gives me an error - `No module named 'letsum'`. Any idea why this happened?

Comment: @cookieclatter, I've created [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ddvODRLYd7EY1ryJZcoL8CR_s3vm4pTs?usp=sharing) showing how you can do it on Colab. Check it out, please

Comment: It's working now. Thank you so much, you're a legend!

Comment: Glad I could help ;)